# How do I wire up the switch for my bathroom fan?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, old-house

I purchased my first house back in February. Overall, it's been great, but we've found the people we bought it from did a little "creative" wiring we've been slowly fixing.

About a month ago, we had a surge that fried the bathroom fan. I had an electrician out to look at it, and he told me that it'd be much cheaper to replace the fan myself using the same model.

*However*, when he had the switch box open, he noted that there were no grounded wires, and the fancy timer switch with the buttons wasn't up to code. He advised me to replace it with a spring switch and capped off the old switch in the meantime.

I've now got my spring switch, but I'm a little confused about how to install it. The instructions and wiring video I watched only seem to indicate that the hot goes into the switch, then another hot wire comes out of the switch and goes to the fan, and then the neutral comes back from the fan and gets wired directly to the neutral line coming in.

However, when I opened the box, here's what I saw:

[image: WTF Electrical]

At some point in the next five years, I'd like to redo the bathroom, including the electrical. However, for now, I really just want my bathroom fan to work.

Here's a couple of pictures inside the fan box.

[image: 12-2?]
[image: Fan connection]

And here's what the wires looks like from the replacement fan's box.

[image: Replacement fan wiring]

What's the best way to wire this up?

Comment: Old style switch loop.  The white is hot or switched hot and should be marked black or red at both ends.  People who are too lazy and want smart switches to turn on from their chair hate them.  Add a picture of the wiring at the fan so we can provide correct connections.  Should find both of those whites connected to hot/black.

Comment: It's an old pattern that's no longer code conformant. Uninterrupted power goes directly to the ceiling box. Only the hot goes to and from the switch through the two wires in a single cable.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I've tried to get past the fan box to the wiring, but it looks like they originally cut a hole through the floor above in order to get it in there, so I'm having a hard time getting to it. (When I replaced the fan, I swapped it without rewiring anything.) Is it possible to diagnose it with those pics? I'm attaching one of what it looks like inside the fan box.

@popham If that's the pattern, can I just wire in a switch into both "hot" lines then?

Comment: With the switch next door wired that way, I'm 99% sure you can just wire the fan's switch analogously. I would probably bridge the two wires to verify that the fan comes on before actually wiring the switch.

Comment: Thanks @popham!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You have two old-style switch loops here

What you see in your switch box are a pair of old-style (no neutral to be had) switch loops.  You should be able to wire your spring-wound timer's brass screws to the unterminated white and black wires in the box.  Don't forget to put a wirenut of the correct size on that grounding connection that's just been twisted together without any splicing device, and add a grounding pigtail from that connection to a grounding screw in the back of the box for that matter!

Comment: This was the answer! Thank you for the help. 